# ¿Cómo se le dice a alguien que tiene los pies grandes?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Al menos para otras partes del cuerpo, la terminación "ón" sirve para dar la idea de que algo es grande:

- Cabeza -> cabezón
- Nariz -> narizón
- Pierna -> piernón
- Oreja -> orejón
- Boca -> bocón

¿Existe alguna terminación que indique que el pie es grande? En Colombia he escuchado "patón" por el uso coloquial de "pata" como pie, pero quisiera saber si existe una forma con la palabra "pie" directamente.

Comment: ¡Muy buena pregunta! // *Patón* funciona en México también.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando el [dirae](https://dirae.es/palabras/?q=pies%20grandes) he encontrado ["patudo"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SC8ktVo)

> 1. adj. coloq. Que tiene grandes patas o **pies**.

No es de extrañar, ya que el sufijo "-udo, -uda" es un sufijo aumentativo que indica "exceso o abundancia, normalmente de alguna parte del cuerpo". Sin embargo, la entrada del DIRAE proporciona otro término menos familiar, usado en Nicaragua, como es "[caitudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dxM1Q0)"

> 2. adj. Nic. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene los **pies grandes**. U. t. c. s.

Supongo que este viene a su vez de [caite](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dvyE3F) que el algunos países sudamericanos designa a una sandalia o tipo de calzado, y que `caitudo` es como decir "zapatilludo".

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, no parece existir palabras que combinen "pie" con alguno de estos sufijos "-on/-udo" como "*piezudo*" o "*piezón*". A pesar de no existir, es bastante probable que se te entendiese correctamente si dijeses que alguien es "piezón" o "piezudo".

Comment: En México hay zonas en las que se dice patón.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que también podría ser **patón**, aunque se refiere a las patas de los animales, podría aplicarse a los pies de una persona.

**Patudo**, a veces tiene la connotación de confianzudo, un **tipo patudo**, en este sentido, sería un hombre que se toma más atribuciones de las que debe respecto de alguna situación o de alguien.

Comment: En Chile a las camionetas de neumáticos grandes se les dice "[patonas](https://www.google.com/search?q=camionetas+patonas&source=lnms&tbm=isch)".